# Schengen visa requirements for seafarers signing off

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, transit-visas

I am a crew member and I'm planning to disembark at one of the Schengen countries. My Schengen visa expired while I was on board. Is it possible to disembark at one of the Schengen countries and then fly home to India (I am an Indian citizen) without a valid Schengen visa, or is it possible to arrange a short term visa?

Comment: I can't quite understand your question. Are you saying that you want to disembark from your ship at a Schengen country (and you don't care which) and then fly to India? Also, just to clarify, you're an Indian citizen?

Comment: I am pretty not sure which country i will sign off. Most probably Spain. Yes i am an Indian citizen. Do these Shengen countries have different visa requirements?

Comment: Why did you apply for the visa (did you visit the Schengen area already, or is it just for flying home from Spain)? Why did it expire (had your ship some unforeseen delay, or is it your fault)? What visa type is it? What countries are you visiting in the Schengen area? What's the last country before reaching Schengen? What country is your ship registered in?

Answer (score 1):

I assume there is some reason why you couldn't apply for a proper visa (that is still valid) in advance, like eg.

- your visa was supposed to be valid when arriving in Spain, but the ship had some unforeseen delays
- you didn't plan to leave the ship in the Schengen are at all (but some reason happened, like sick relatives, job terminated, or whatever)
- you didn't even know where you will be at the date when you're supposed leave (no idea what ship you're on, but for some types I guess that's possible)

or something like that, and that you have some sort of evidence of that (even if it's "ask the captain", just something).

Without any reason why you didn't just apply in an embassy/consulate in India, it's going to be hard.

Furthermore, I assume

- that you have your passport, it's valid, not damaged and so on
- your passport does not expire in the next 6 months
- your expired visa still exists and you can show it to the border guard (big help)
- you have evidence that you work on the ship
- in Spain, you just want to go to an airport to fly to India, nothing more (especially no visit to another Schengen country).

In this case, you can be pretty sure to get get a very-short-term visa (max. 5 days, possibly shorter) directly from the authorities in the harbor in Spain.

Sources:
The [Schengen border guard handbook](http://register.consilium.europa.eu/doc/srv?l=EN&f=ST%2015010%202006%20INIT) section 3 and 7

Comment: Btw., according to https://ec.europa.eu/home-affairs/what-we-do/policies/borders-and-visas/visa-policy_en, about 0.7% of issued Schengen visas are on the border because of reasons why a embassy application wasn't possible. Of these, Spain issued 22%. Good chances

Comment: The version of the handbook you link to is eleven years old and obsolete.  The five-day limit concerns type B transit visas, which no longer exist.

Answer (score 1):

You ought to be able to get a visa at the port were you disembark, under Article 36 of the [Schengen Visa Code](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX:02009R0810-20160412).  However, this is subject to the requirements set out in Annex IX, and it requires cooperation of your employer:

> Article 36
>
> Visas issued to seafarers in transit at the external border
>
> 1.  A seafarer who is required to be in possession of a visa when crossing the external borders of the Member States may be issued with a visa for the purpose of transit at the border where:
>
> (a) he fulfils the conditions set out in Article 35(1); and
>
> (b) he is crossing the border in question in order to embark on, re-embark on or disembark from a ship on which he will work or has worked as a seafarer.
>
> 2.  Before issuing a visa at the border to a seafarer in transit, the competent national authorities shall comply with the rules set out in Annex IX, Part 1, and make sure that the necessary information concerning the seafarer in question has been exchanged by means of a duly completed form for seafarers in transit, as set out in Annex IX, Part 2.
>
> 3.  This Article shall apply without prejudice to Article 35(3), (4) and (5).

The most relevant part of Annex IX:

> II.   Leaving service from a vessel that has entered a Member State port (exit from the territory of the Member States)
>
> — the shipping company or its agent shall inform the competent authorities at that Member State port of entry of seafarers subject to visa requirements who are due to leave their service and exit from the Member States territory via a Member State airport, land or sea border. The shipping company or its agent shall sign a guarantee in respect of those seafarers that all expenses for the stay and, if necessary, for the repatriation costs of the seafarers will be covered by the shipping company,
>
> — the competent authorities shall verify as soon as possible whether the information provided by the shipping company or its agent is correct and shall examine whether the other conditions for entry into the territory of the Member States have been satisfied. The travel route within the territory of the Member States shall also be verified e.g. by reference to the (airline) tickets,
>
> — where the verification of the available data is positive, the competent authorities may issue a visa the authorised stay of which shall correspond to what is necessary for the purpose of the transit.

Comment: ...but you forget article 35. (And then, I can't really see what your answer adds what wasn't already said, other than the original formulation which could be read in the link too (a link which won't go away for many years))